# R: create publishable tables of several regression outputs

Tags: r, output, linear-regression, summary, broom

I´ve ben analyzing data for a paper and have now obtained results in mutiple linear regression. However the summaries R provides are not really fir for publication in the final paper. Also I have specified one variable in several different ways, to showcase the robustness of the results.

Hw can I create a nice, exportable table in R, that contains Variable Names (ideally also allows to name the variables in a more informative way), estimates, standard errors, robust standard errors p values and ideally also the significance indicators? For illustration:

I have summary outputs like this:

```
Residuals:
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-50.868  -4.644   1.583   7.054  20.490 

Coefficients:
                           Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)  
(Intercept)               4.710e+01  1.848e+01   2.549   0.0136 *
Var1                     -8.588e-01  2.201e+00  -0.390   0.6979  
Var2                      2.486e+00  1.055e+00   2.357   0.0220 *
log(specification1)       3.376e+00  2.152e+00   1.569   0.1223  
Var4                     -3.651e-04  2.797e-04  -1.305   0.1971  
Var5                      4.809e+00  2.654e+00   1.812   0.0753 .
Var6                     -8.706e+00  6.972e+00  -1.249   0.2170  
Var7                     -8.172e+00  5.755e+00  -1.420   0.1612  
Var8                     -3.276e+00  7.067e+00  -0.463   0.6448  
Var9                     -1.477e+01  7.849e+00  -1.882   0.0650 .

---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

and

```
Residuals:
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-48.881  -5.699   0.956   8.947  17.888 

Coefficients:
                           Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)  
(Intercept)               4.258e+01  1.750e+01   2.405   0.0195 *
Var1                      4.298e-01  2.120e+00   0.200   0.8421  
Var2                      5.179e+00  1.027e+00   2.122   0.0271 *
log(specification 2)      2.050e+00  9.435e-01   2.173   0.0338 *
Var4                     -1.420e-04  2.261e-04  -1.513   0.1356  
Var5                      4.584e+00  2.511e+00   1.826   0.0730 .

---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

and I would like to get to a table looking something like this:

```
             Model1                                             Model2
Intercept    Estimate  Std.Error  p robust_Std.Error robust_p  Estimate  Std.Error  p  robust ...
Var1
Var2
Var3
Var4
Var5
Var6
Var7
Var8
Var9
```

which in the columns of course contains the values of the estimates. Is there a function/ package that does that nicely?

Thanks in advance

Comment: see the `stargazer` package

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you to use the `broom` package, like this:

```
fit1 <- lm(mpg ~ ., mtcars)
broom::tidy(fit1)

# # A tibble: 11 x 5
#    term        estimate std.error statistic p.value
#    <chr>          <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>   <dbl>
#  1 (Intercept)  12.3      18.7        0.657  0.518 
#  2 cyl          -0.111     1.05      -0.107  0.916 
#  3 disp          0.0133    0.0179     0.747  0.463 
#  4 hp           -0.0215    0.0218    -0.987  0.335 
#  5 drat          0.787     1.64       0.481  0.635 
#  6 wt           -3.72      1.89      -1.96   0.0633
#  7 qsec          0.821     0.731      1.12   0.274 
#  8 vs            0.318     2.10       0.151  0.881 
#  9 am            2.52      2.06       1.23   0.234 
# 10 gear          0.655     1.49       0.439  0.665 
# 11 carb         -0.199     0.829     -0.241  0.812
```

It will extract a `tibble` from the output of the `lm` function.

---

If you have more than one model and you wanna set all the tibbles together with common terms you can deal with it this way:

Create a list `x` of your models.

```
fit1 <- lm(mpg ~ cyl + disp + gear, mtcars)
fit2 <- lm(mpg ~ cyl + hp   + drat, mtcars)

x <- list(fit1, fit2)
```

You can use this solution:

```
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

# set names for the list
names(x) <- paste("Model", seq_along(x), sep = "_")

# tidy them up
x <- map(x, broom::tidy)

# set the list names at the beginning of each column
x <- imap(x, ~set_names(.x, paste(.y, names(.x), sep = "_")))

# rename each term column as "term"
x <- map(x, ~rename_with(.x, str_replace, pattern = ".*term", replacement = "term"))

# join them all together
reduce(x, full_join, by = "term")
```

It returns the output you asked for:

```
# A tibble: 6 x 9
  term        Model1_estimate Model1_std.error Model1_statistic Model1_p.value Model2_estimate Model2_std.error Model2_statistic Model2_p.value
  <chr>                 <dbl>            <dbl>            <dbl>          <dbl>           <dbl>            <dbl>            <dbl>          <dbl>
1 (Intercept)         34.0              4.76              7.13    0.0000000925         22.5              7.99               2.82        0.00880
2 cyl                 -1.59             0.724            -2.20    0.0366               -1.36             0.735             -1.85        0.0747 
3 disp                -0.0200           0.0109           -1.83    0.0774               NA               NA                 NA          NA      
4 gear                 0.158            0.910             0.174   0.863                NA               NA                 NA          NA      
5 hp                  NA               NA                NA      NA                    -0.0288           0.0153            -1.88        0.0704 
6 drat                NA               NA                NA      NA                     2.84             1.52               1.87        0.0725
```

If your list has more than two models, the code will be stable.